# Get the last element and append?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the last element of the JSON response?

```
...
    var array_response = $.parseJSON(response); 
    var index = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
        var stato = array_response[index]["name"];
        var id = array_response[index]["id"];

        $('#owl-sensori-allarmi').append("");
    } // END FOR
}
```

Here is the JSON code:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "place": "Stanzina",
    "state": "1"
 }, {
    "id": "3",
    "place": "Sala",
    "state": "0"
}]
```

Thanks!

SOLVE:

```
    var array_response = $.parseJSON(response);
    var room = array_response[array_response.length -1]["id"];
```

Comment: If it is array try indexing with `length-1`. Can you show your JSON code?

Comment: I'm with @ThaiDoan `array_response[array_response.length -1]`

Comment: Thanks for answer :)
This is the json:
[{"id":"1","place":"Stanzina","state":"1"},{"id":"3","place":"Sala","state":"0"}

Comment: Side comment: If you're using `$.ajax` or `$.get` or something similar, then you shouldn't call `$.parseJSON` yourself. There's an option for that.